# Debugging Steps for Ethernet Over Coax Dropping Connection (Actiontec ECB6200)

Tags: ethernet, coaxial-cable

I have an ethernet over coax backhaul between two ends of my home, using Actiontec ECB6200 devices https://www.actiontec.com/products/ecb6200/

There is a coax link light that has started to turn off periodically throughout the day. I have not figured out what it corresponds to. Obviously, when this happens, my network stops working. I have power cycled both ethernet coax adapters but it still is happening.

The system has been working reliably for over a year and just started having these issues in the past month or 2.

Potential causes:

- these Actiontec adapters are failing somehow
- the coax cable has deteriorated in some way

These devices operate at a relatively high frequency (1000-1500Mhz), is there a way I am test/validate the coax is performing as expected before I replace the Actiontec devices?

I have looked into various coax testers but they seem to be basic connectivity / short testing. Do I need frequency testing?

TIA

Comment: Is the cable direct from one adapter to the other?

Comment: I don't know much about MoCA debugging but in the 2020 decade if I was going to put any effort or money into a problem like this I would take the opportunity to abandon it, and instead run Cat6 to two or three critical locations that would be the backbone of a wifi mesh.   It won't be long before maintaining and upgrading your MOCA boxes will be like upgrading your 1200 baud modem for your AOL account.

Comment: @longneck the coax is connected as part of an existing coax cable / internet setup for the unit. Likely splitter/filter somewhere. It's on the second floor and so it's hard to inspect.

Comment: @jay613 haha, fair. It might come to that but I would love to see if we can leverage the existing wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Use a long length of coax with fittings to test the operation of the Actiontec units. Use it coiled up or run it down the hallways between the 2 send/receive units. Then you can determine if the problem is the house coax or the 2 adapters.